# How to replace the comma in the text file with a point in LabVIEW?

Tags: csv, text, labview

I am new at LabVIEW. I created a program to measure some diodes. The data in the text file look like this:  0,002 instead of 0.002.

I don't know where the problem is and how to solve it. Any advices?

[image]

Comment: What would you like to do: convert these commas in the text file or in the application, before values are written to the file? There can be many reasons why it looks like this (and it's not a bug, a comma is used as a decimal point separator in many countries). Please post your block diagram here, so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using a computer that has a locale that has a ',' as the decimal indicator (German, Dutch). Look up your [labview.ini](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/LabVIEW_configuration_file) file and change or add the [useLocaleDecimalPt](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/LabVIEW_configuration_file/Front_Panel#useLocaleDecimalPt) parameter to False.
If you are using a build executable the filename won't be labview.ini but xxx.ini where xxx is your application name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Format into String" function you can define the decimal sperator in the format string. In your case it would be something like: `%.;%f;%f`